# Ultimate SAML Component Pro library

Tags: dll, saml, saml-2.0

We are planning to buy the license for SAML component from component pro but i want to make sure that it can be integrated with PHP moodle environment. We will be having ASP.Net web application which will act as IDP and user clicking on our website will transfer to Moodle PHP website which is being maintaned by other company. Its only us who will be using the Ultimate SAML component from component pro to create a SAML response and send it to them. But how can they read that SAML response without using the component pro library because the SAML response that i am sending is an object of SAMLResponse class from the library. I checked out all the sample projects and all the IDP and SP in the sample projects from component pro and all of them uses the comp pro library to create and read SAML responses. Basically i want create a SAML response using this library which can be read by SP without using the component pro library and we can have successful SSO integration. I apologies if i was not clear present my scenario.

Comment: FWIW, please see cheated.by.safabyte.net which shows Component Pro likely represents the latest incarnation of stolen SAML software. TY

Comment: @iokevins is right - see https://www.componentspace.com/forums/12576/ComponentPro-sells-stolen-SAML-libraries for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAML is a XML based standard. The SAMLResponse you are talking about will be marshalled to XML before the message is sent.

As long as your component and Moodle is correctly implementing SAML it doesn't matter what you are using to generate the SAML messages.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @Stefan. SAML is a protocol standard - how you implement it is irrelevant.

It's kind of like having English as a standard and the one side writes a message using Notepad and the other side reads it using Word.

Notepad != Word but because they both use English it doesn't matter.

Just a word of warning - SAML is a huge protocol - not all implementations support all sections.

Answer (score 0):

My SAML plugin for moodle, based on simplesamlphp should be compatible with that IdP. Is free and many organizations are using it.  https://moodle.org/plugins/view.php?plugin=auth_saml